# Is it possible to check if a LUKS device has been damaged by a foreign person?

Tags: encryption, luks, disk-encryption

Let's assume I lost a LUKS encrypted USB pen drive. I think the file system type (ext4/fat32/...) doesn't play a role. A foreign person finds it. Of course he cannot access my data because he doesn't have the password. But he can change a single byte in the middle of the "raw" data so the data is damaged.

After the pen drive is returned to me, is it possible to verify my data was damaged or not?

I thought reading the whole mapper device will cause an I/O error but unfortunately it does not. I also checked `dmesg`.

```
# create an all zero 100MiB file
dd if=/dev/zero of=moh bs=100M count=1

# format it as LUKS device
/usr/sbin/cryptsetup luksFormat moh

# map it to /dev/mapper/moh
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen moh moh

# initialize mapper file to zero
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mapper/moh

# close LUKS device
sudo cryptsetup luksClose moh

# overwrite 1MiB with zeroes at offset 10MiB. After this the LUKS device is damaged.
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=moh conv=notrunc bs=1M seek=10 count=1

# open LUKS device and see if it complains
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen moh moh

# read all data to see if it complains
sudo dd if=/dev/mapper/moh of=/dev/null
```

The above commands proofs that opening and reading a damaged LUKS device does not produce any error.

Please note that I don't want to perform any file system checks. Instead I want to verify whether the LUKS device is untouched on the encryption level.

Because I am looking for a single command to verify a luks device I hope you understand this is not a programming question more suitable for SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible but not with "plain" LUKS, you need to set up authenticated encryption. This is possible with LUKS v2, you need to create the LUKS device using the `--integrity` option with `luksFormat`. This will basically add checksums for the encrypted data to ensure integrity, without it LUKS/dm-crypt simply doesn't care (or know) what is on the disk and if you overwrite it with zeroes it will "decrypt" those zeroes. See the *Authenticated disk encryption* section in [cryptsetup man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cryptsetup.8.html) for more details.

Comment: In some cases, one could also go for integrity-checking *within* the encrypted volume – for example, by using a file system that does data checksumming. In general I'd say, using dmcrypt's/LUKS integrity layer is the way to go

Comment: Is it possible to add integrity checking to an existing luks2 device?